# Mockito mock calling real method implementation when attempting to stub package protected method

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to stub a method using Mockito 1.8.5, but doing so calls the real method implementation (with "" as parm values) which throws an exception.

```
package background.internal; //located in trunk/tests/java/background/internal

public class MoveStepTest {

    @Test
    public void testMoveUpdate() {
        final String returnValue = "value";
        final FileAttachmentContainer file = mock(FileAttachmentContainer.class);
        doReturn(returnValue).when(file).moveAttachment(anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
        //this also fails
        //when(file.moveAttachment(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(returnValue);

        final AttachmentMoveStep move = new AttachmentMoveStep(file);
        final Action moveResult = move.advance(1, mock(Context.class));
        assertEquals(Action.done, moveResult);
    }
}
```

The method I'm trying to mock looks like this. There are no final method or classes.

```
package background.internal; //located in trunk/src/background/internal


   public class FileAttachmentContainer {
        String moveAttachment(final String arg1, final String arg2, final String arg3) 
                throws CustomException {
            ...
        }

        String getPersistedValue(final Context context) {
           ...     
        }
    }
```

And the class I'm passing the mock looks like this:

```
package background.internal; //located in trunk/src/background/internal
public class AttachmentMoveStep {

    private final FileAttachmentContainer file;

    public AttachmentMoveStep(final FileAttachmentContainer file) {
        this.file = file;        
    }

    public Action advance(final double acceleration, final Context context) {
        try {
            final String attachmentValue = this.file.getPersistedValue(context);
            final String entryId = this.file.moveAttachment(attachmentValue, "attachment", context.getUserName());

            //do some other stuff with entryId
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            e.log(context);
        }    
        return Action.done;
    }
}
```

What is causing the real implementation to be invoked and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you add the code that actually is executing the test?

Comment: Is `FileAttachmentContainer` or the method `moveAttachment()` final? Mockito cannot mock final methods.

Comment: Is moveAttachment really called with the values of anyString() ?

Comment: Is your test class in the same package as `FileAttachmentContainer`?  If not, it won't be able to access `moveAttachment`.

Comment: @markus - No.  The return value of `anyString()` is `""`.  But calling it adds a matcher to an internal data structure within Mockito, which the stubbing process reads from.

Comment: This looks like perhaps an injection problem - like the mock is set up correctly, but then the mock is not really the object that is being used in the test.  If you could show us the code of the test and the code actually being tested, that would help a lot.

Comment: +1 @jhericks i aggree. AttachmentMoveStep use another File instance but not the injected one.

Comment: @DavidWallace The test and real code are in the same package, but located in different folders and compiled into two differnt jars. Making moveAttachment public stops the mock from calling the real implementation. However, when this.file.getPersistedValue(context) is called within AttachmentMoveStep the real implementation is called. But, when called inside the test class the mock returns null, as expected. –

Comment: Actually your unit test as posted works fine. If you still need help, maybe you could tell us more about your jar setup?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The method you are mocking is not accessible to the Mockito code.

Because your test code and your code under test are in the same package, the compiler lets you set up your mock that way, but at runtime, the Mockito library has to try to access `moveAttachment`, but it's not working in your case.  This appears to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=127) or [known limitation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/OSGi) in Mockito as it should support that case, (and in fact, does support it in most cases).

The easiest thing to do would be to make `moveAttachment` a public method.  If that is not an option, then first question whether you want to even mock it.  What happens if the real method gets called?

The last option is to use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) to treat the `moveAttachment` method as a private method and mock it that way.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. It also looks like other people have run into it: http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=127 Thanks

Comment: This is not correct. In general Mockito can mock package private methods without a problem. This bug seems to be a problem with OSGi/sealed jars or something similar.

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff, if that is true, would PowerMock still do the trick? If so, I'll change my answer to try to better reflect the "why" part of it.

Comment: @jhericks I don't know :-( Just guessing about the cause of Jake's problem based on the bug report. Sorry, I see now that was not very helpful. But Mockito can definitely mock package private methods, I use that quite often.

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff I've edited my answer to hopefully be more accurate.  I think the remedies I suggest will still work, but I recognize them as "workarounds" rather than any user error.

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff I found http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/OSGi.  The last chapter on this page suggests that OSGi's use of separate classloaders impacts what happens with package-private methods.  In effect, package-private doesn't mean exactly the right thing when you're using OSGi.  Not really a Mockito bug then, but it may be something that the Mockito team will want to find a work-around for.

Comment: I am agree with @Arendv.Reinersdorff, Mockito is able to mock method with package visibility. Si i don't understand why this answer have been accepted.

Comment: I think it was accepted because the remedy fixed the problem.  Jake Walsh didn't know that the explanation for _why_ was incorrect.  Anyway, I have since edited the answer to (hopefully) correct the _why_ part to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @jhericks i make my own response. Your response should be accepted, if and only if he specify that he use osgi (it isn't a detail).

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the accepted response.

I think, you have to provide more details on your environment. I can't reproduce your problem. I write the following code in a maven project :

```
package background.internal; //located in src/main/java

public class FileAttachmentContainer {
    String moveAttachment(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    String getPersistedValue(Context context) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

and

```
package background.internal;

public class AttachmentMoveStep {

    private FileAttachmentContainer file;

    public AttachmentMoveStep(FileAttachmentContainer file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public Action advance(double acceleration, Context context) {
        String attachmentValue = file.getPersistedValue(context);
        file.moveAttachment(attachmentValue, "attachment", context.getUserName());
        return Action.done;
    }
}
```

and the following test pass

```
package background.internal; //located in src/test/java

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MoveStepTest {

    @Test
    public void testMoveUpdate() {
        String returnValue = "value";
        FileAttachmentContainer file = mock(FileAttachmentContainer.class);
        doReturn(returnValue).when(file).moveAttachment(anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
        //this also works
        //when(file.moveAttachment(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(returnValue);

        AttachmentMoveStep move = new AttachmentMoveStep(file);
        Action moveResult = move.advance(1, mock(Context.class));
        assertEquals(Action.done, moveResult);
    }
}
```

My project use the following dependencies :

- jdk1.7.0_05
- junit-4.10.jar
- mockito-all-1.9.0.jar
- javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar
- objenesis-1.2.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.1.jar

Comment: This is no answer at all.  It is just stating that you can't figure out why the questioner is having the problem.  The question was, "What is causing the real implementation to be invoked? and how can I prevent it?"  I answered the "how can I prevent it" part but only had guesses on the "What is causing it" part.  This answer has neither.  This answer just says that it _should_ work and you don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: @jhericks, you are right, i don't why and for me this is a problem. I think we must get to the bottom of thing and find the root cause of the problem. Not just provide some workaround.

Comment: @gontard Did you compile into two separate jars? One with the test and one with the implementation?

Comment: @JakeWalsh yes it works too. Can you provide more details on your environment ? Are you using osgi, proguard... ?

Comment: @gontard I think the issue I was hitting is the same one you opened in https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/168, can't stub public method inherited from a package visible class

Comment: @JakeWalsh ok. I tought your problem have been solved by the other answer.