# mockito - what to do when anyString is not ok

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I want to mock with PowerMockito/Mockito only one static method from a class.

I did 'spy' on it.

I really need the doAnswer method because the answer is customized according to the parameter value of the function.

Further, I did something like:

```
doAnswer(...).when(class,methodname, anyString());
```

The ugly issue here - a thrown exception - is becuase:

my method throws exception when called with null/empty string param

the anyString method returns exactly what I do not want: null or empty string

Remark: argThat also returns null.

What can be done here?:)

Thank you!

StackTrace:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: key can't be null
    at java.lang.System.checkKey(System.java:771)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:647)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2015)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:893)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:867)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:463)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:105)
```

Later edit: 
this type of 'when', when you give method and params, is more rigid from what I see - If I put, instead of anyString "a", then everything works excellent. In this 'when', it is considered the result of anyString(), which is empty, which ruins everything....

Comment: I'm not too familiar with PowerMockito, but since when does the .when method do an invocation of your method. As far as I understand and experienced it, it's just some condition when it will return your given Answer. So I would suspect that your actual Test is handing over some empty/null String to your method.

Comment: nope, it all falls at this line: when(class,methodname, anyString());

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: I still doubt that it should do an invocation on your method if you setup a mock for it. At least for Mockito it's known that it may invoke the actual method and not using a mock (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12010643/1377224). Maybe your setup isn't right (we would need your test)?

Comment: this type of 'when', when you give method and params, is more rigid from what I see - If I put, instead of anyString "a", then everything works excellent. In this 'when', it is considered the result of anyString(), which is empty, which ruins everything....

Comment: please post your testcase and a minimal class under Test.

Comment: philnate, thank you for your good intention... my hunch is that when expects real objects, not generic anyString. My question, in this case, is about an alternative.

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? If you just want `anyString` and you don't care about the value (as long as it is not empty or null) then just use a random value. If, on the other hand, you want to check the actual result of `doAnswer` given exact inputs, then put the string you want and check the result accordingly. I don't exactly know how mocking class works, I have been taught it is not "good practice" and mock should be done only on interfaces.

Comment: doAnswer does a...small processing of the parameter sent to the mocked method. Mock is used quite a lot...when you want to 'implant' a value and watch the rest of the application's behavior.

Comment: You should either use matchers for all arguments or matchers for no arguments. I'm not sure if that's your problem though. Could we see the code?

Comment: Why not simply making this a non static method?