# Mockito calling real methods when attempting to stub methods implemented on a package private superclass

Tags: java, mockito

This may be the same root question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996809/mockito-mock-calling-real-method-implementation-when-attempting-to-stub-package), but much easier to reproduce.

The issue is when stubbing interface methods on a mocked public class which extends a package private class that has the interface method implementations. Mockito will call the real interface method implementations in the package private class. See the following example.

Interface

```
public interface DontCallMe {
    int dontCallMeSuper();
    int dontCallMe();
}
```

Package default class which implements one of the interface methods.

```
abstract class PackagePrivate
        implements DontCallMe {

    @Override
    public int dontCallMeSuper() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("don't call me super");
    }
}
```

Public subclass of the package private class that implements the other.

```
public class Public
    extends PackagePrivate {

    public Public() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int dontCallMe() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("don't call me");
    }
}
```

Test class

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleJunit {

    @Test
    public void testStaticConstructorInnerClass() {
        final Public comparable = mock(Public.class);
        when(comparable.dontCallMe()).thenReturn(1);
        when(comparable.dontCallMeSuper()).thenReturn(1);
    }
}
```

Results of running the test

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: don't call me super
at PackagePrivate.dontCallMeSuper(PackagePrivate.java:6)
at Public.dontCallMeSuper(Public.java:1)
at ExampleJunit.testStaticConstructorInnerClass(ExampleJunit.java:19)
```

I can work around this by making `PackagePrivate` public, but that is not great. Is there any way for me to stub methods implemented on a PackagePrivate class?

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the interface (`DontCallMe`) instead of the class (`Public`):

```
    final DontCallMe comparable = mock(DontCallMe.class);
```

Or, if you need to mock methods that are in `Public` but not in `DontCallMe`, you can create a new interface and mock that instead.

For instance, using your original `DontCallMe` definition, you can do this:

```
public interface IPackagePrivate extends DontCallMe {
    int extraMethod();
}

------

abstract class PackagePrivate implements IPackagePrivate { 
    public int dontCallMeSuper() { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("don't call me super");
    } 
}

------

public class Public extends PackagePrivate { 

    public Public() { 
        super(); 
    } 

    public int dontCallMe() { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("don't call me");
    }

    public int extraMethod() { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("extra method");
    } 
} 

------

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock; 
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when; 
import org.junit.Test; 

public class ExampleJunit { 

    @Test
    public void testStaticConstructorInnerClass() { 
        final IPackagePrivate comparable = mock(IPackagePrivate.class);
        when(comparable.dontCallMe()).thenReturn(1);
        when(comparable.dontCallMeSuper()).thenReturn(1);
        when(comparable.extraMethod()).thenReturn(1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: True, unfortunately the actual code I'm mocking is much more complicated then the example and I can't mock the interface.

Comment: I've appended more to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some more googling, this is a known mockito bug. See https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/168. Fix proposed in https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/171 targeted for mockito 2.0