# Why mockito make a call for parent method when stubbing

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

Why mockito make a call for stubbed method.

Why it make an actual call for **func** under when..thenReturn
I have checked when doing debugging.

```
  @Test
    public void function(){
       MyClassChild obj = mock(MyClassChild.class);
       when(obj.func("abc")).thenReturn(3);
    }
    ...
    class MyClass {
       public int func(String s) {
          if (s.equals("abc"))
             return 3;
          else
             return 1;
       }
    }

class MyClassChild extends MyCLass {

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996809/mockito-mock-calling-real-method-implementation-when-attempting-to-stub-package

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to replay your issue by having the following test:

```
public class StackTest {
    @Test
    public void mockedFunction() {
        MyClass obj = mock(MyClass.class);
        when(obj.func("abc")).thenReturn(3);

        assertEquals(3, obj.func("abc"));
    }

    @Test
    public void function() {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();

        assertEquals(7, obj.func("abc"));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass {

    public int func(String s) {
        if (s.equals("abc"))
            return 7;
        else
            return 9;
    }
}
```

All tests where executed successfully. Can you show how you are invoking the test?

Comment: `MyClass` in the OP is not public...Probably that's the issue. You could have a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996809/mockito-mock-calling-real-method-implementation-when-attempting-to-stub-package) as @Som Bhattacharyya points in a comment

Comment: I have figure it out, I was mocking child class and try to  "when..then()" in parent function.SI i think mockito does not work properly in parent class method.